# Send message to my Whatsapp from Java Client

Tags: java, whatsapp

I have a Java project and I would like to get notified of certain runtime events by receiving a message in my personal Whatsapp account. I was wondering if this is even possible and if so, how can I accomplish this? Is there an API or Java library that I should be aware of?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp Inc. doesn't allow sending messages programmatically for personal accounts. But WhatsApp has started taking requests for business accounts in which they might allow certain programming features like integrating with your own code for sending messages etc.

I had once written a program using selenium to send message via WhatsApp Web. It worked perfectly fine. This was for experimental purpose only.

There are few 3rd-party libraries available but you run the risk of getting your number blocked. WhatsApp tries to detect if you are running such libraries. And if they catch then they will immediately block the mobile number.

Selenium method doesn't have such risk. Because you will be using WhatsApp Web only (via selenium).

For your application, the method suggested by @C-Sway is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at Telegram as an application for this.

https://telegram.org/

AFAIK whatsapp will be tied to a mobile/cell number, which will hinder you from the outset, whilst creating your own private telegram channel to monitor automation on your site is very simple, they encourage bot use for this kind of thing and you'll find guides on how to create them below:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples

Additionally Telegram can be installed on any phone and the notifications are very reliable and customisable. Enjoy.